# PUT request is returning an error with flask

Tags: python, mysql, curl, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I use Flask in an API application and I have this function:

```
@app.route('/v1/myapi/editperson/<int:id_person>)', methods=['PUT'])
def edit_person(person_id):

    req_data = request.get_json()
    firstname = req_data.get('firstname')
    lastname = req_data.get('lastname')
    session.query(model.Persons).filter(model.Persons.id==person_id).update( firstname, lastname)
    session.commit()
    session.close()     
    return jsonify(req_data)
```

When I execute this curl request:

```
 curl -i -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"firstname": "myfirstname", "lastname": "mylastname"}' http://localhost:5000/v1/myapi/editperson/38
```

I get this error:

```
HTTP/1.0 404 NOT FOUND
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 27
Server: Werkzeug/0.14.1 Python/2.7.6
Date: Wed, 04 Jul 2018 07:17:09 GMT
Proxy-Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

{
  "error": "Not found"
}
```

I do have a row in the database with the id = 38 so I don't know why the request doesn't find it. 
I use SQLAlchemy to query the database.

Any clues?

Comment: You are doing a POST via curl and method defined is PUT.

Comment: I edited my question but PUT gives the same output: 404 not found

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Indeed PUT/POST but also:

```
@app.route('/v1/myapi/editperson/<int:id_person>)', methods=['PUT'])
```

vs.

```
@app.route('/v1/myapi/editperson/<int:id_person>', methods=['PUT'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your annotation specifies that this API just allow `PUT` method. But you request this API through `POST` method. Try:

```
curl -X PUT ....
```

Answer (score 0):

Your route passes id_person but your query uses person_id